# Why do I get an int when I index bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the first char of a byte-string in python 3.4, but when I index it, I get an `int`:

```
>>> my_bytes = b'just a byte string'
b'just a byte string'
>>> my_bytes[0]
106
>>> type(my_bytes[0])
<class 'int'>
```

This seems unintuitive to me, as I was expecting to get `b'j'`.

I have discovered that I can get the value I expect, but it feels like a hack to me.

```
>>> my_bytes[0:1]
b'j'
```

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: The hack of using a range like `my_bytes[0:1]` really helped me write Python2/Python3 compatible code. I'd love to see an answer that covers the best practice for compatible code addressing this issue. For example: `ord(my_bytes[0])` gives an int in Python2, yet `my_bytes[0]` gives an int in Python3. To work in both, I'm using `ord(my_bytes[0:1])` which seems really ugly for Python3.

Comment: you answer helped me, I couldn't find the best approach to work with bytes and avoid the integer conversion when accessing an index, thanks.

Comment: I noticed the same phenomena with lists made from bytearray and bytestring.

`type(list(b'abctest').pop(0))` give `<class 'int'>`.

`type(list(bytearray(b'abctest')).pop(0))` give `<class 'int'>`.

`type(bytearray(b'abctest').pop(0))` give `<class 'int'>`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `bytes` type is a [Binary Sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview), and is explicitly documented as containing a sequence of integers in the range 0 to 255.

From the documentation:

> Bytes objects are immutable sequences of single bytes.
>
> [...]
>
> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that `0 <= x < 256`[.]
>
> [...]
>
> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object `b`, **`b[0]` will be an integer**, while `b[0:1]` will be a `bytes` object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1).

Bold emphasis mine. Note than indexing a string is a bit of an exception among the sequence types; `'abc'[0]` gives you a `str` object of length one; `str` is the only sequence type that contains elements of its own type, always.

This echoes how other languages treat string data; in C the [`unsigned char` type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) is also effectively an integer in the range 0-255. Many C compilers default to `unsigned` if you use an unqualified `char` type, and text is modelled as a `char[]` array.

Comment: "while b[0:1] will be a bytes object of length 1(This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)"can you please explain this sentence i didn't get it?

Comment: @CY5: sorry, what part did you get? If you create a (Unicode) string, `'abc'[0]'` produces another string object `'a'`. If you use the same slice as the example used for the `bytes` object, `'abc'[0:1]` also produces a string object of length one, `'a'`.

Comment: @CY5: but for a `bytes` object, `b'abc'[0]` produces an integer (`97`), and slicing produces a `bytes` object of length one (`b'abc'[0:1]` produces `b'a'`).