# Python3: Iterating a binary string turns character into integer

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, iteration

I feel like I am missing something trivial here:

I recently made the jump over to Python3 (Using PyDev in Eclipse).
I have a project that calculates entropy values, and contains the following bit of code:

```
data = b'NVGI\x19\x01\x10\x00'
seen = dict(((chr(x), 0) for x in range(0,256)))
for byte in data:
    seen[byte]+=1
```

The binary string in data is much longer, but this is sufficient for demonstration purposes.

With python3 this code results in an KeyError. With python2.7 this works with no issues at all.

This is due to the fact that iterating over *data* returns an integer (78 in this case) while *seen* expects a character 'N' instead.

The curious thing is that in python2.7 the same code will produce the expected character 'N'.

I have for now band-aided this by doing:

```
seen[ord(byte)] += 1
```

Can someone please try and replicate this or tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use a `counter`?

Comment: You want the same code to run in both Python 2 and 3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249597/why-do-i-get-an-int-when-i-index-bytes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267452/iterate-over-individual-bytes-in-python3

Comment: Even with a counter, I would be forced to do `seen[data[counter]]` where `data[counter]` still returns an integer instead of and character.

Comment: @Ilja: Thanks, that's actually insightful. Still extremely weird to have such undocumented differences between python 2 and 3.

Comment: @kennytm No, just python3. I also tested it side by side on my old python2 setup because the result was unexpected and found the difference.

Comment: Hardly undocumented: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Comment: I should correct: Not documented where I looked, since I assumed this to be an issue with dictionary construction or list iteration, not the underlying bytes data type.

Comment: The mismatching expectation is that `chr(x)` would produce a byte. It produces a `str`. I'm a little surprised that `ord` accepts `bytes` objects, actually. In your particular case, though, it would appear either an array or a collections.Counter is a better choice than a dictionary, and letting the bytes be ints.

Comment: Exactly. For now I fixed my code by removing the `chr(x)`. I may or may not Upgrade towards the counter when the deadline is less pressuring. Thank you again for your valuable input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) the **elements of a binary string are `int`s**.

Indeed:

```
>>> type(data[0])
<class 'int'>
```

This was also specified in the ["*What's New In Python 3.0*" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

So your you can solve the issue by for instance **constructing the dictionary** like:

```
seen = dict(((x, 0) for x in range(0,256)))
```

Or you can do it the **opposite way**:

```
data = b'NVGI\x19\x01\x10\x00'
seen = dict(((chr(x), 0) for x in range(0,256)))
for byte in data:
    seen[chr(byte)]+=1
```

But a more elegant solution is to simply use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter(data)
```

Which generates:

```
>>> Counter(data)
Counter({16: 1, 1: 1, 86: 1, 25: 1, 73: 1, 71: 1, 78: 1, 0: 1})
```

A `Counter` is a **subclass of `dict`**, so all dictionary operations are supported on the counter.

In case you want the counter to contain `str`ing values, you can do it like:

```
result = Counter(chr(x) for x in data)
```

This gives:

```
>>> Counter(chr(x) for x in data)
Counter({'\x00': 1, 'G': 1, 'I': 1, '\x01': 1, 'V': 1, 'N': 1, '\x10': 1, '\x19': 1})
```

Note that if you query a counter for a *non-existing key*, it will **return `0`**. So you also save on memory so to speak since you do not necessarily have counts for all 256 values.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Maybe add a link to @Yann's comment to the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Comment: @Araiguma: that's indeed a good suggestion. Modified.