# python 2 python 3 hexadecimal indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have a python hexadecimal like this:

```
variable = b'\x80pu\xa6\x7f\xfe\xb9\x1d\xaf'
```

in python 2 if i do variable[0] i get '\x80' but in python 3 it converts into int for me and it return 128.

i guess i can try to convert the answers back to hexadecimal like this:

```
hex(variable[0])
```

but its a whole array and i might not be integers.
i was looking for a better way to do this since:

```
hex() takes only integer and also it returns a string not the hexadecmial version
```

i want the actual x80 not 128

how would i do this?

code i am working with:

```
p = b'\x80pu\xa6\x7f\xfe\xb9\x1d\xaf'
f = struct.unpack('>B', p[0])[0]

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

it works in python2 but not in python 3

Comment: `and it might not be integers` In python3 bytes is *defined* as a sequence of integers. It's hard to understand what a single bytes can be other than a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Maybe, [Why do I get an int when I index bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249597/why-do-i-get-an-int-when-i-index-bytes) is helpful here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm so glad I found your question - I just hit the same problem with python2 code that we were converting to python3.  My solution to your problem was to use slices (which is covered by the SO question:  [Why do I get an int when I index bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249597/why-do-i-get-an-int-when-i-index-bytes)).

Specifically for your code:

```
p = b'\x80pu\xa6\x7f\xfe\xb9\x1d\xaf'
f = struct.unpack('>B', p[0:1])[0]
```

Observe that I changed your expression `p[0]` (which evaluates to int in python3) to a 1-byte slice `p[0:1]` (which is of type <class 'bytes'>). By contrast, python2.7 considers `p[0]` as <type 'str'> and `p[0:1]` also as <type 'str'>.